# Duplicate Items Using Join in NHibernate Map

Tags: nhibernate, join, mapping

I am trying to retrieve the individual detail rows without having to create an object for the parent.  I have a map which joins a parent table with the detail to achieve this:

```
Table("UdfTemplate");
Id(x => x.Id, "Template_Id");
Map(x => x.FieldCode, "Field_Code");
Map(x => x.ClientId, "Client_Id");

Join("UdfFields", join =>
{
    join.KeyColumn("Template_Id");

    join.Map(x => x.Name, "COLUMN_NAME");
    join.Map(x => x.Label, "DISPLAY_NAME");
    join.Map(x => x.IsRequired, "MANDATORY_FLAG")
        .CustomType<YesNoType>();
    join.Map(x => x.MaxLength, "DATA_LENGTH");
    join.Map(x => x.Scale, "DATA_SCALE");
    join.Map(x => x.Precision, "DATA_PRECISION");

    join.Map(x => x.MinValue, "MIN_VALUE");
    join.Map(x => x.MaxValue, "MAX_VALUE");
});
```

When I run the query in NH using:

```
Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(UserDefinedField))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("FieldCode", code)).List<UserDefinedField>();
```

I get back the first row three times as opposed to the three individual rows it should return.  Looking at the SQL trace in NH Profiler the query appears to be correct.  The problem feels like it is in the mapping but I am unsure how to troubleshoot that process.  I am about to turn on logging to see what I can find but I thought I would post here in case someone with experience mapping joins knows where I am going wrong.

Comment: I changed the direction of the join so the mapping works Template > Fields.  It's not ideal as I have to create additional objects/maps but it results in a similar query being executed and the end result that I'm looking for.  Still open for ideas if anyone has them on how to join child > parent.

Comment: Have you tried using a DistinctRootEntity transformer? Would be something like               .SetResultTransformer(CriteriaUtil.DistinctRootEntity)

Comment: I did - it would only return a single row rather than the three distinct rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found aboutn about SetResults transformer here :

http://www.coderanch.com/t/216546/ORM/java/Hibernate-returns-duplicate-results

Which makes your code:

```
Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(UserDefinedField))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("FieldCode", code))
    .SetResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DistinctRootEntity)
    .List<UserDefinedField>();
```

Cheers
John